# Algorithm for building a graph from a set of points

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic, filtering

I need some input on solving the following problem:

Given a set of unordered (X,Y) points, I need to reduce/simplify the points and end up with a connected graph representation.

The following image show an example of an actual data set and the corresponding desired output (hand-drawn by me in MSPaint, sorry for shitty drawing, but the basic idea should be clear enough).

[image: Example input and output]

Some other things:

- The input size will be between 1000-20000 points
- The algorithm will be run by a user, who can see the input/output visually, tweak input parameters, etc. So automatically finding a solution is not a requirement, but the user should be able to achieve one within a fairly limited number of retries (and parameter tweaks). This also means that the distance between the nodes on the resulting graph can be a parameter and does not need to be derived from the data.
- The time/space complexity of the algorithm is not important, but in practice it should be possible to finish a run within a few seconds on a standard desktop machine.

I think it boils down to two distinct problems:

1) Running a filtering pass, reducing the number of points (including some noise filtering for removing stray points)

2) Some kind of connect-the-dots graph problem afterwards. A very problematic area can be seen in the bottom/center part on the example data. Its very easy to end up connecting wrong parts of the graph.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for solving this? Cheers.

Comment: So the dots on the upper graph are noise, and the thick line is the important part?

Comment: @John Yeah, exactly. The dots are (mostly) concentrated around certain lines, which I need to turn into a graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [K-nearest neighbors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_nearest_neighbors) (or, perhaps more accurately, a sigma neighborhood) might be a good starting point. If you're working in strictly Euclidean space, you may able to achieve 90% of what you're looking for by specifying some L2 distance threshold beyond which points are not connected.
- The next step might be some sort of [spectral graph analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering) where you can define edges between points using some sort of spectral algorithm in addition to a distance metric. This would give the user a lot more knobs to turn with regards to the connectivity of the graph.

Both of these approaches should be able to handle outliers, e.g. "noisy" points that simply won't be connected to anything else. That said, you could probably combine them for the best possible performance (as spectral clustering performs a lot better when there are no 1-point clusters): run a basic KNN to identify and remove outliers, then a spectral analysis to more robustly establish edges.